# How to get unique elements from two lists of strings in scala?

Tags: scala

I have two list to compare:

List one:

```
List("one","two","three","four")
```

List two:

```
List("one","two")
```

how can I get the unique values from these two lists?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique values"? Do you want the *set union* of the two lists, or those elements which only appear in exactly one list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your two lists are `r1` and `r2`, and assuming you want the values in each list that are not present in the other:

```
r1.filterNot(r2.contains) ::: r2.filterNot(r1.contains)
```

or

```
r1.diff(r2) ::: r2.diff(r1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Turn them into sets, and get the intersection. You may then turn it back to `Seq` if you want, but first ask yourself if they had to be `Seq` in first place, instead of `Set`.

```
scala> List("one","two","three","four").toSet & List("one","two").toSet
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(one, two)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use The difference operator for Set `&~`

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html

Answer (score 1):

I use `List(1, 2, 3, 4) ::: List(1, 2, 5) distinct` for this issue. It returns `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following for O(m+n) running time (assumes input arrays are sorted).

```
def mergeUniqueSortedArrays( A: Array[String], B: Array[String] ): Array[String]= {
  val n = A.length
  val m = B.length
  var C = Array[String]()
  var i = 0
  var j = 0
  while (i < n && j < m) {
    if (i == n) {
      if ( B(j) != A(i-1) ) {
        C :+= B(j)
      }
      j+=1
    }
    else if (j == m) {
      if ( A(i) != B(j-1) ) {
        C :+= A(j)
      }
      i+=1
    }
    else {
      if ( A(i) < B(j) ) {
        if (C.length == 0 || A(i) != C(C.length-1)) {
          C :+= A(i)
        }
        i+=1
      }
      else if ( B(j) < A(i) ) {
        if (C.length == 0 || B(j) != C(C.length-1)) {
          C :+= B(j)
        }
        j+=1
      }
      else {
        if (C.length == 0 || A(i) != C(C.length-1)) {
          C :+= A(i)
        }
        i+=1
        j+=1
      }
    }
  }
  return C
}
```

--

NOTE:  If the input arrays are not sorted, then you can easily sort the input arrays and it will run in in O( max{(n + m), (n log n)}) time, assuming n>m.

NOTE: O(n + m) time technically assumes that string length is bounded by constant k, but you aren't going to get around that anyway.